# What these kernel panic logs relating to GPU Reset mean?

Tags: xcode, kernel-panic, gpu

I'm having a really annoying issue and I would like to know what's causing it (Xcode triggers it).

When I'm using Xcode and the storyboard editor, selecting or moving anything will occasionally cause a complete system failure or freeze. Not 10 minutes ago I was trying to set the class for a UIView whilst playing some music and I suddenly heard a loud buzzing sound through my headphones and my screen just went black. The computer rebooted and showed the kernel panic screen.

This is the first time it completely crashed the system as it usually just completely locks up and requires a force restart.

I check the logs and I have these files matching the day of the crash:

Kernel_2018-01-25-033831_Noahs-MacBook-Pro.gpuRestart: https://pastebin.com/vNxQAbWH
Kernel_2018-01-25-033918_Noahs-MacBook-Pro.panic: https://pastebin.com/inMsqHFp

I have created pastes on pastebin for these files as they contain quite a bit of information and would flood this post.

It seems to be GPU related, I don't think it's a hardware issue as I've been pushing this GPU pretty hard and never have any issues with it other than Xcode.

I have filed a bug report with Apple about this but I'm just wondering if anyone can figure out if it's a user kext or something to make sure it's not a problem on my end.

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro (14,3) with the Radeon Pro 560 and High Sierra 10.13.2.

Comment: I have exactly the same problems for some time on a late 2015 iMac, with Xcode 9.2, macOS 10.13.3, and selecting (some particular) items in the storyboard designer. The screen freezes, only the mouse is moveable. The only choice is a force restart or wait for a kernel panic to happen. It seems indeed GPU related, in my case AMD Radeon R9 M390. Some selection actions are 'unsafe' while others are OK, like selecting items in the object tree view and properties inspector.

Comment: I have the exact same issue that you just described with the same type of MBP (14,3) and macOS 10.13.3. The kexts in backtrace are also identical and it occurs to me when I'm using IB in Xcode as well. I found [this article](https://objective-see.com/blog/blog_0x27.html) about this issue (tldr: it's an unpatched bug and sadly, that's it).

Comment: One more thing: I noticed that the panic mostly occurs when I'm **editing text directly on the storyboard** by double-clicking on a label/button and not by using the Attributes inspector.